# R Funktion selber schreiben -> Moderationsanalyse

Tags: r, function, output

I'm trying to create my first function in R to calculate moderation analysis.
But now a problem accured I cannot solve :/
When I run my function, I don't get any output..
I also tried print() and return() with the same result.
Any recommendations?

```
Moderation <- function(Mod, UV, AV) {
meanUV <- mean(UV, na.rm = TRUE)
sdUV <- sd(UV, na.rm = TRUE)
ZUV <-((UV - meanUV)/sdUV)

meanMod <- mean(Mod, na.rm = TRUE)
sdMod <- sd(Mod, na.rm = TRUE)
ZMod <- (Mod - meanMod)/sdMod

Interaktion <- ZUV*ZAV
Moderation.fit <- 'AV ~ ZUV + ZMod + Interaktion'
summary(sem(model = Moderation.fit, data = MyData, meanstructure = TRUE))
}

Moderation(MyData$SKK, MyData$ZDT2, MyData$HO4)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To ensure that a maximum number of people may help you, do post in english.

Comment: Could you add some reproducible data so that we can run your code? We are missing `MyData`

Comment: Where is `ZAV` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your function is that you refer to `MyData` in the last line even though you do not pass this dataset to the function. Actually, the function does look into your global environment and finds `MyData` there. But your z-scored variables and `Interaktion` are not included in this version of `MyData`, so the function reports an error about "missing variables in dataset".

It works with the following changes:

```
Moderation <- function(Mod, UV, AV) {
  require(lavaan) #This ensures the function works even if you did not do library(lavaan) first.
  ZMod <- scale(Mod) #I simplified stuff here. The "scale" function is equivalent to what you did.
  ZUV <- scale(UV)
  Interaktion <- ZUV*ZMod
  MyData <- as.data.frame(list(ZMod=ZMod, ZUV=ZUV, AV=AV, Interaktion=Interaktion)) #Here, MyData is generated so that you can use it further below
  Moderation.fit <- 'AV ~ ZUV + ZMod + Interaktion' #nothing changed here
  summary(sem(model = Moderation.fit, data = MyData, meanstructure = TRUE))
}
```

I tested it with the popular `mtcars` dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
Moderation(mtcars$am, mtcars$hp, mtcars$mpg)

##lavaan 0.6-7 ended normally after 28 iterations
##
##  Estimator                                         ML
##  Optimization method                           NLMINB
##  Number of free parameters                          5
##                                                      
##  Number of observations                            32
##                                                      
##Model Test User Model:
##                                                      
##  Test statistic                                 0.000
##  Degrees of freedom                                 0
##
##Parameter Estimates:
##
##  Standard errors                             Standard
##  Information                                 Expected
##  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured
##
##Regressions:
##                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##  AV ~                                                
##    ZUV              -4.043    0.560   -7.225    0.000
##    ZMod              2.633    0.513    5.134    0.000
##    Interaktion       0.014    0.527    0.026    0.979
##
##Intercepts:
##                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##   .AV               20.094    0.505   39.785    0.000
##
##Variances:
##                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##   .AV                7.670    1.917    4.000    0.000
```

Viel Erfolg und Spass damit!